# this.setState() not updating state with passed array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing an array which contains the following credentials.:

```
//Snippet variable contains an array which looks like this

{
details: test, 
_id: "5d9d0b506ee7d03a54d8b1f6", 
name: "TEST GREEN", 
content: "<div style="background-color:green; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>", 
}
```

The array is recieved by a function, the function updates the state.
**The state looks like this:**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.showModal = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      snippets: [],
      edit: null,
      show: false,
      sid: '',
    }
  }
```

**The function looks like this**

```
  handleModal = snippet => {
    console.log(snippet) //pastes output found in the snippet array above
    console.log(this.state) //{snippets: Array(3), edit: null, show: false, sid: ""}
    this.setState({ edit: this.snippet })
    console.log(this.state)//{snippets: Array(3), edit: null, show: false, sid: ""}
    this.setState({ sid: snippet._id })
    this.showModal.current.showModal()
  }
```

I know I have two setStates. I am trying to isolate the problem.

`edit: null` in the state should be becoming `edit: Array(1)` but setState seems to be failing.

Comment: In first `setState` you have used value for `edit` as `this.snippet`. Wouldn't you use `snippet` instead of `this.snippet` ?

Comment: `setState` is async, so logging directly after the function call won't do you much good unfortunately as it will not contain the updated values.

Comment: I guess you need to `setState({edit: snippet})` and not `this.snippet`

Comment: Also, you can set multiple values within a singular `setState` call. For example: `this.setState({ edit: snippet, sid: snippet._id });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two problems:

### `this.snippet`

You should update your state using `snippet` instead of `this.snippet`

```
this.setState({ edit: snippet })
```

### `this.setState` is asynchronous

The method `this.setState()` is asynchronous. Then, if you log right after it, the state problably won't be updated already. If you want to see the state after the update, passes a callback to the method, like below:

```
this.setState({ edit: snippet }, () => console.log(this.state))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `snippet` instead `this.snippet`.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` doesn't update state immediately. It can take some time. If you want to do some actions only after state has been updated, put you code in `setState` callback.

```
this.setState({...newState}, () => {
 // actions after state update.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this.snippet is noting, you should use

```
this.setState({ edit: snippet })
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous and the state is not updated immediately. Try to use the second parameter of setState - callback function

`this.setState({ sid: snippet._id }, () => this.showModal.current.showModal())`